# When using IK the player head is looking at down the ground instead looking at the object target up what can be the problem?

Tags: unity, c#

This script is attached to the player :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class CharController : MonoBehaviour
{

    protected Animator animator;
    public bool ikActive = false;
    public Transform lookObj = null;
    public float lookWeight = 2f;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    //a callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {

        if (animator)
        {

            //if the IK is active, set the position and rotation directly to the goal. 
            if (ikActive)
            {
                // Set the look target position, if one has been assigned
                if (lookObj != null)
                {
                    animator.SetLookAtWeight(lookWeight);
                    animator.SetLookAtPosition(lookObj.position);
                }

            }

            //if the IK is not active, set the position and rotation of the hand and head back to the original position
            else
            {
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the lookObj is a sphere or a cube it's working fine but if the lookObj for example is a big spacecraft now the player head will look to the ground down and not to the spacecraft up :

[image: Player is looking at down the ground instead up the spacecraft]

The problem is that the center of the spacecraft is at the bottom this is a screenshot when it's showing the spacecraft at regular when it's in Pivot mode :

[image: Pivot]

Now when I click on the Center button now the center of the object is at the bottom :

[image: After clicked on the Center button it's showing that the spacecraft center is at the bottom]

Is there any way to fix it maybe eve fix it ?

Comment: Where is the center point of the spacecraft game object? Sometimes you import models from a modeling program, and the vertices are all very far away from the origin point. One thing you might want to try is create an empty gameObject, confirm that the IK can track that object properly and *then* assign the mesh to that object. That might give you some insight into what's wrong.

Comment: @Philipp You right. When I click in the view scene on the Center button I see the center of the spacecraft is at the bottom. I will add a screenshot with explain.

Comment: @Philipp Edited my question.  So now that we know what is the problem , is there any way to fix it maybe automatic or maybe need to make some changes to the model ?

Comment: I see that you have an Animator on that "Anim_Flyer" game object while the actual mesh appears to be somewhere in the child-hierarchy (which isn't visible in your screenshot). Does that animator control its position? Or does it control something else?

Comment: The animator control something else the spacecraft propellers on the sides and make the spacecraft in idle animation.

Comment: @Philipp but I think I found a solution not sure if it's a good one but it seems to be working. I just added an empty GameObject and dragged the Anim_Flyer and made it  a child of the empty GameObject.  Is that a good logic solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you imported a model which is not properly centered. The visible parts of the mesh appear to be far above the origin point.

Ideally you should fix that in a 3d modeling program by making sure that the 0:0:0 point is in the middle of the geometry. But when you don't want to mess with the asset, then you could fix that by wrapping the object in a parent and then changing the relative position of the object so its visual center is the position of its parent. Although it appears that the 3d mesh is already parented to the `Anim_Flyer` gameObject, so you might be able to change the relative position of the object(s) which are the children of that object.

Another option is to add a separate empty child to the flyer which serves as an IK target point for other objects. Adding objects like that can be useful when you want objects which look at another object to not center their view on the origin of the subject but on a specific eye-catching feature of the subject (like the yellow ring thing of this mesh), and perhaps even have multiple of such features and use them depending on context. It also plays well with animations, because you can parent those IK-targets to the sub-objects which are being animated.